# How can I format my css text so that the result is in 2 columns?

Tags: html, css, list, pseudo-element, css-counter

I want to recreate the following text in html and css:

[image]

So far, without css, I wrote in html:

```
<p><b>noun</b></p>
<p>1. an optical instrument, often attached to the eyepiece of a microscope, by which
the image of an external object is projected on a sheet of paper or
the like for tracing.</p>
```

But how can I divide the `1` and the rest of the text so it stays like in the original image?

Comment: Is changing the HTML an option?

Comment: yes of course, sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `ordered list` ( HTML element `ol`)

Example below:

```html
<p><b>noun</b></p>
<ol>
  <li>an optical instrument, often attached to the eyepiece of a microscope, by which
the image of an external object is projected on a sheet of paper or
the like for tracing.
  </li>
</ol>
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to change your markup, there are other options upon which you can build upon.

For instance using a `table` and `psuedo` elements and a `counter` for the numbering:

```css
 body {
    counter-reset: counter;
 }
.list {
  display: table;
}
.list:before {
  display: table-cell;
  counter-increment: counter;
  content: counter(counter) '.';
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p><b>noun</b>
</p>
<p class="list">an optical instrument, often attached to the eyepiece of a microscope, by which the image of an external object is projected on a sheet of paper or the like for tracing.</p>
<p class="list">an optical instrument, often attached to the eyepiece of a microscope, by which the image of an external object is projected on a sheet of paper or the like for tracing.</p>
```

Comment: For semantic purposes a definition list might be better here - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KgzBOb

Answer (score 0):

As @kukkuz already said you can use an `ordered list`. Then if you want to get exactly the same result as the image you posted you can then change the layout of your list in your CSS like so:

```
ol {
  padding-left:1em;
}

li {
  padding-left:1em;
}
```